# Menu list doesn't appear in div as expected

Tags: html, css

I want to create a Navigation Menu with this sidebar.

It should have links but `ul` list is not displaying on `div` Element

I want to do this using CSS only.

Pure CSS is required because I don't have any scripting language knowledge

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <title>SideBar</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons
            "/>
            <style type="text/css">
                /*
                 #button {
                 display: block;
                 text-decoration: none;
                 margin-top: 20px;
                 margin-left: 50px;
                 color: white;
                 width: 20px;
                 height:20px;
                 font-size: 30px;
                 transition: width 0.5s;
                 background-color: black;
                 text-align: center;
                 padding-bottom: 30px;
                 box-sizing: border-box;
                 }*/

                #button {
                    margin-top: 20px;
                    margin-left: 50px;
                    font-size: 30px;
                    cursor: hand;
                }

                #sidebar {
                    position: absolute;
                    background-color: black;
                    left: 0px;
                    top: 0px;
                    width: 0px;
                    height: 100%;
                    transition: width 0.5s;
                    opacity: 0.7;
                }

                #screen {
                    position: fixed;
                    background-color: tan;
                    height: 100%;
                    width: 100%;
                    left: 0px;
                    top: 0px;
                }

                #button:hover + #sidebar {
                    width: 200px;
                }

                #sidebar:hover {
                    width: 200px;
                }

            </style>
        </head>

        <body>

            <div id="screen">

                <i class="material-icons" id="button">menu</i>

                <div id="sidebar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#1">Nav 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#2">Nav 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#3">Nav 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <hr />
                <div>
                    Hello
                </div>
            </div>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? It's not well-formatted right now, but it seems to work. http://jsfiddle.net/ps0reqgd/

Comment: The ul only makes an unordered list. If you remove the ul you will have an ordered list (numbered not bulleted) Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: I think what the OP is referring to is that the UL is displaying on the page and not on the slide out sidebar. Look at the examples in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21425244/css-for-a-sidebar-menu-that-folds-in-and-out

Comment: wanted to add content in sidebar div element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in your CSS you have `#sidebar{ width: 0px;}` the `ul` cannot be contained inside that `div`, instead play with the `left` value rather than `width` [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p01wud8v/1/)

```css
#button {
     margin-top: 20px;
     margin-left: 50px;
     font-size: 30px;
     cursor: hand;
 }
#sidebar {
     position: absolute;
     background-color: black;
     left: -200px;
     top: 0px;
     width: 200px;
     height: 100%;
     transition: width 0.5s;
     opacity: 0.7;
     padding-top:50px;
 -webkit-transition: left 1s;
transition: left 1s;
 }
 #sidebar ul {
 list-style-type:none;
 }
 #screen {
 position: fixed;
 background-color: tan;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 }
 #sidebar:hover, #button:hover + #sidebar {
 left: 0;
 -webkit-transition: left 1s;
transition: left 1s;
 }
```

```html
<div id="screen"><i class="material-icons" id="button">menu</i>

    <div id="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#1">Nav 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#2">Nav 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#3">Nav 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div>Hello</div>
</div>
```

Note: added `transition: left 1s;` to make the transition of sliding into the page and out with the `-webkit-` for supporting issues